# Programmatically managing groups & users in GSuite via the API

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, g-suite

I have a script that leverages the `gcloud` tool to create service accounts for a project.

**I'd like to be able to create GSuite groups and add the service accounts to them within the same script as creating the service accounts**, so I don't have to do it manually in the web UI.

Preferably, I would like **as much of this to be done via the CLI as possible**, including the initial setup of service accounts and GSuite authentication etc.

There is a lot of conflicting information when it comes to authenticating between gcloud and gsuite and how to automate GSuite tasks using gcloud service accounts.

What is the process to:

- Get the required authentication information to submit requests to the GSuite API
- Give permissions/scopes to whatever is required to the obtain the above
- Actually use that auth to create a group/add a user to a group/etc.

I would prefer to do any API requests either using a CLI tool (such as `gcloud`) or CURL. If a client SDK is required, I would prefer the NodeJS one.

#### Update

To clarify what I've tested so far, after wading through tons of out of date documentation on Google's developer portal, I:

- Enabled the "Admin SDK API" for my project in GCloud (Google regularly references the 'Directory' API, which isn't something that can be enabled in the GCloud APIs, so I assume they're referring to the Directory API within the Admin SDK API)
- Created a service account and gave it `owner` role for the project
- Enable domain-wide delegation on the service account to get its Client ID
- In the Google Admin (GSuite) console, I gave the service account client ID the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group` in both "Security -> Manage API client access" and "Security -> API Controls -> Domain-wide Delegation"
- Used the [oauth2l](https://github.com/google/oauth2l) tool with curl to generate a bearer token with the scope `admin.directory.group`
- Attempted to use that bearer token to create a group using the following command: `curl --request POST   'https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups'   --header "$(oauth2l header --json /home/<file containing the secret for the service account> --scope admin.directory.group)"   --header 'Accept: application/json'   --header 'Content-Type: application/json'   --data '{"email":"test@my-gsuite-domain.com"}'   --compressed`
- Gsuite returned a nice handy 403 `Not Authorized to access this resource/api`.

Over all of the Google documentation they advise you to try these things out using the API Explorer, which doesn't exist anymore.

In the [directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites) pre-reqs page it describes setting up the API for the Admin console - The options described there also do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

TL:DR: You need to work with [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/get-start/getting-started) from [G SUITE SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk)

#### Get the required authentication information to submit requests to the GSuite API

On [Directory API: Prerequisites page](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites) we can read the steps you need to follow to **Set up your API**:

> 1 Enable the API access from the Admin console in order to make
>   requests to the Directory API. To enable the API, log in to your admin
>   account and select **Security**. If you do not see Security listed, select
>   **More controls** and then **Security** from the options shown in the gray
>   box. Select API reference, and then select the checkbox to **Enable API**
>   access. Save your changes.
>
> 2 Set up a new project in the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) and activate Admin
>   SDK service for this project

#### Give permissions/scopes to whatever is required to the obtain the above

On [Directory API: Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing) you can read more about the process for [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing#OAuth2Authorizing) and the scopes you need. Since you want to manage only groups, you need to add the scope for "Scopes for groups, group aliases, and group members". The scope you need to add is:

**Scope:**
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group

**Meaning:**
Global scope for access to all group operations, including group aliases and members.

#### Actually use that auth to create a group/add a user to a group/etc.

Since you will interact with the API using BASH, you will need to perform queries to the API using CURL. So all the examples I will post are using CURL.

On [Directory API: Groups](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups) you can read the operations you can perform and how to perform such operations.

So, for example, if you want to create a group to need to perform a POST operation to "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups" with a payload of a JSON with the next format:

```
{
   "email": "sales_group@example.com",
   "name": "Sales Group",
   "description": "This is the Sales group."
}
```

So the CURL command will look like this:

```
curl --request POST \
     --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --header "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>" \
     --data '{"email":"sales_group@example.com","name":"Sales Group","description":"This is the Sales group."}' \     https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups
```

A successful response returns an HTTP 201 status code. Along with the status code, the response returns the properties for the new group.

If you have problems getting your TOKEN you can read more in some post about how to get OAUTH 2.0 Tokens:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593022/list-google-drive-files-with-curl
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44063975/get-access-token-of-google-api
https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/concepts/curl-example
https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl/

Comment: Thank you for your response - Unfortunately I'm stuck at the first step - The options "API Reference" and "Enable API Access" do not exist under the Security category in Google Admin, so I imagine the docs you're referring to are outdated. This is why I'm having so much trouble doing these things - it's very difficult to find accurate documentation!

Comment: In my testing, I enabled the Directory API in GCloud, created a service account for it, gave it domain-wide delegation, then used the API Permissions in Google Admin to give the group scopes to the service accounts client ID. I then tried to use the Google Admin SDK for NodeJS to list groups with the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var set to the service account credentials location. It seems to authenticate, but 403's when trying to list groups.

Comment: It also doesn't help that the API explorer is linked literally everywhere - but it doesn't exist anymore!

Comment: Hi there. I followed my own answer to test it and I was able to perform the operations. When I go to (Google Admin)[https://admin.google.com/] I found exactly the options as described on my answer. Can you please confirm if you are logging into the correct console. Also, are you a GSUITE or Cloud Identity Free customer?

Comment: Hi - That's interesting. I am indeed logging into the correct console, and I'm a Gsuite customer. When clicking on 'Security', the only available options related to API is the "API Permissions" section, which allows me to manage app access to google services. It may be that API is already enabled, please see the update in my answer for what options were available and what I tried to do.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue as OP, docs are terrible.
Solved by granting "Groups Admin" role to my ServiceAccount on the Google Workspace Admin interface: Admin roles > Groups Admin > Service Account